# Rails thread secure variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, mutex

I'm having an issue about thread secure variables. I have a controller method which sends sms to given numbers. But if users makes request at the same time variables are being overwritten.
I know RoR s not thread-secure and i have to make it but i couldnt do it with live response. If i would take all data from user and do it in a background job, it would be easier.

For example lets say first user tries to send sms to x number with the content a and the second user tries to send sms y number with the content b. If they make the requests at the exactly same moment x number getting two sms with content a and b.

```
def create
  success = false
  message = nil
  status  = 422
  if params[:receivers].present? && params[:title].present? && params[:content].present?
    if params[:is_future_sms].present? && params[:is_future_sms].to_s == 'true' && !params[:send_date].present?
      render json: {success: false, message: 'Insufficient Parameter'}
    else
      sms = @account.sms_objects.new(sms_object_params)
      sms.sms_title_id = set_sms_title_id
      sms.receivers = sms.receivers.to_s
      receivers = NumberOperations.sanitize_receivers_with_hash(sms.receivers)
      if receivers.count > 0
        total_count = sms.credit(sms.content)
        sms_balance = sms.balance(sms.content)
        receivers.map{|r| r[:balance] = sms_balance}
        sms_balance = receivers.count * total_count

        if @account.can_afford_sms?(sms_balance)
          if sms.save
            SendSmsJob.perform_later(sms.id, receivers)
            success = true
            message = 'Messages created successfully'
            status  = 201
          else
            success = false
            message = sms.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
            status  = 422
          end
        else
          success = false
          message = 'Insufficient Credit'
          status  = 422
        end
      else
        success = false
        message = 'No valid number'
        status  = 422
      end
    end
  else
    success = false
    message = 'Insufficient Parameter'
    status  = 422
  end
  render json: { success: success, message: message }, status: status
end
```

I guess i can solve the problem with mutex and Thread.new but when i use it it doesnt give the response to user.

```
def create
  th = Thread.new do
    # all code here
  end
  th.join
end
```

this works well but doesnt response at the end.

Comment: Two requests to a Rails application will not share the same controller instance and therefore I would argue that the code you shared is thread-safe. There might be issues in other parts of your application, but in your example, there is nothing that would be a red flag to me - like a global variable or a shared resource. Can you please elaborate on why you think your code is not thread-safe? Btw: Rails is [thread-safe per default](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html) for a long time.

Comment: I've made 200 requests from 2 different computers and with different accounts with a loop at the same time. I sent numbers from 1 to 100 to a number and from 100 to 200 to another number. There's no way to mix them up right? But the result was really annoying.  Messages were completely mixed.

Comment: And when i log every line and every variable of this code; i can see variables are overwritten from different requests.

Comment: What does `NumberOperations.sanitize_receivers_with_hash` do? How is it implemented?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hsyntnc/3bf94bed97f1b28d9f8939f8028149f2

but even if i disable this file and move all code to controller it doesnt change anything.

Comment: You have to debug your controller code under you tests, instead of trying Mutex. I bet, there is no issue with Rails thread safe, just controller/test bug.

Comment: Yes, but its not happening on debug. It's happening only if two requests are made exactly at the same time. Its like variables are trying use the same space on memory.

Comment: `SendSmsJob ` - what do you have here?

Comment: @michal.samluk it doesnt matter whats there. when i log it i can see numbers already changed before that line. i'm not changing anything with code even if i would do, i guess its not possible to share data between requests.

Comment: How are you logging those numbers? Can you show an example? The code seems fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/dPIz8uL

Comment: Thank you all guys. I switched from puma to unicorn and it works good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeyyy! I found the solution. 
I've changed my server from puma to unicorn. And it works properly now.